# Avoid first Google OAuth 2.0 authorization

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-api, google-oauth, access-token, google-sites

I've made an app who use OAuth from Google to access to Google Sites API. It works perfectly, but I want less user action, especially the first time when you must accept google's permissions, get authorization token, to get access and refresh token.

I want to know if it's possible to avoid all this steps (for users, and do this behind the application), in the code with HTTP requests for example or google libs, and just have to inform a google account (mail/password) to get an access/refresh token.

Have you any tips or knowledge about this ?

Thanks by advance

Comment: So you want Google to just give you access to a users data without asking the user first if you can have access? That doesn't sound very secure.  No you cant do that that's what Authentication is all about.

Comment: No, that's not what I want, because as you said, it's not very securized. I want to avoid Google Authorization for the final user, and do it seamlessly by the code. Finally, users will only give basic credentials and will be authorized automatically.

Answer (score 0):

As i was using google analytics api i made some research and the minimum process is: 
user click authenticate link on your web page, then is redirected to external google webpage when is prompted securely for login and password. and nothing else. 
This oauth refresh token you can automate then - read about this in google docs - there is some info about this. i made all by changing a little simple hello world analytics app from google code. 
As i remember You had to know what class in php is, and changing oauth wrapper in simple apps. It can store and process refresh tokens automatically - user needs to enter login and password as i said but it can be stored in cookies, so made once.

Comment: And what if I make some HTTP POST requests to get an authorization, with getting cookies or responses from google ? The perfect way should be a login/password, and with this credentials make some requests to get an authorization token, another request to get access and refresh token, and that's all.

Comment: you have to redirect to google authorization which redirects you to url you specify in your api configuration options. Then you can work with api and get refresh tokens. Do You want to avoid google authorization completely?

Comment: I've found a solution and I'm on it : I can authentify myself to google with a simple account (with a HTTP Request) and now I try to simulate a click to avoid the authorization with another HTTP Request (POST method)